# « Nulle part » ou « nul part » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre, accord, indications-de-lieu

Je n'arrive pas à me faire une opinion sur comment il faut écrire « nul(?) part ».

*Part* étant du féminin, il me semble, je verrais **nulle**, mais ça me choque sans je sache pourquoi, et avec les moteurs de recherche je vois autant de *nul part* que de *nulle part*.

[Sur le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/part) je vois :

> Nulle part. V. nul I A 1 e.

Ça aide !

Dans l'immédiat je voudrais écrire correctement : *Cette personne arrive de nul(?) part*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Le site dont tu donnes la référence donne la réponse, la façon d'écrire correcte est : "nulle part", dans tous les cas.

Dans google, il y a autant de *nul part* car il y a beaucoup de personnes ne sachant pas écrire correctement le français :)

Dans ton exemple : *Cette personne arrive de nulle part.*

Comment: Ou plutôt, il y a l'usage, et ce qui est considéré comme "correct". L'usage sera peut-être correct un jour. Il y a probablement des tournures maintenant "correctes" qui ne l'étaient pas auparavant.

Comment: @Frank L'usage certes, mais *"part"* étant féminin, *"nulle"* est logiquement accordé. Nulle part, nul endroit, nulle place, nul lieu.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps - C'est vrai :-)

Comment: @Frank Mais bon l'usage pourrait en faire un mot unique, genre "nulpart" comme on a "gendarme", pourquoi pas.

Comment: `Dans google, il y a autant de nul part`... Faux, il y a très nettement plus de "nulle part".

Answer (score 9):

Il renvoie à l'entrée *nul* du dictionnaire en donnant la forme principale qui sert à l'indexation, mais c'est un adjectif donc il s'accorde bien et il est bien utilisé accordé à l'endroit référencé.

Answer (score 0):

Je ne pense pas que cette expression soit "un adjectif", mais plutôt un adverbe
au même titre que "ailleurs", que je ne vois pas écrit "ailleurse", ou "partout" qui ne s'écrira jamais "partoute". En revanche, pourquoi ne pas l'écrire "nul part" ou "nulle part", sans prétendre au respect d'un accord quelconque (au fait "conque" est-ce féminin ou masculin ?).

A bon entendeur (ou bonne entendeuse, ou ...drice. Salut !)

Comment: Pardon, pas un "pro...verbe", mais un "ad...verbe"

Comment: L'expression est une locution adverbiale mais elle est composée d'un adjectif, *nul*, et d'un nom, *part*, qui est féminin. Il n'y a donc aucune raison de ne pas accorder l'adjectif avec le nom auquel il s'applique.

Answer (score 0):

Voici ce que dit [cet article](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/orthographe/nul-part-ou-nulle-part/) :

> On écrit toujours « nulle part » : on écrira toujours « nulle part »
>   avec « nul » prenant la forme féminine. En effet l’adjectif « nul »
>   s’accorde en genre avec le substantif  « part », ce qui peut prêter à
>   confusion (on peut écrire « nul » comme « nulle » en fonction du genre
>   du substantif qui lui est apposé). Aussi, on notera que « nulle part »
>   est une locution adverbiale invariable, on ne l’écrit donc jamais «
>   nul part ». Selon la définition du CNRTL, « nulle part » signifie « en
>   aucun lieu ». Enfin, on utilise toujours la forme suivante: ne (ou n’)
>   … nulle part (par exemple : « je ne pourrai aller nulle part ce soir
>   »).